# Why does `mkdtemp()` fail when called in googletest?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, posix, googletest

I've created a small RAII class that creates a unique temporary directory and deletes it again upon destruction. On Linux, it uses `mkdtemp()` to achieve this:

```cpp
// temporaryDirectoryPath is an std::vector<char>
// containing u8"/tmp/nuclex-pixels-unittest-XXXXXX"

// Let mkdtemp() sort out a unique directory name for us (and create it!)
const char *directoryName = ::mkdtemp(&temporaryDirectoryPath[0]);
if(directoryName == nullptr) {
  perror("mkdtemp() failed."); // DEBUGGING. REMOVE.
  throw std::runtime_error("mkdtemp() failed.");
}
```

**This works just fine when run on its own: [runnable code on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/RVivsv)**

---

However, if I use that same code inside a [GoogleTest 1.8.1](https://github.com/google/googletest/releases/tag/release-1.8.1) unit test declared like this:

```cpp
TEST(MyTestFixture, CanFlumbleTempDirectory) {
  TemporaryDirectoryScope temporaryDirectory;
  // Could call temporaryDirectory.GetPath() here...
}
```

It fails:

```
Passing the following to mkdtemp(): /tmp/nuclex-pixels-unittest-XXXXXX
mkdtemp() failed.: Invalid argument
```

How can GoogleTest be interfering with `mkdtemp()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you pass to `mkdtemp` is not reliably null-terminated:

```
      // Then append our directory name template to it
      const char directoryNameTemplate[] = u8"nuclex-pixels-unittest-XXXXXX";
      {
        const char *iterator = directoryNameTemplate;
        while(*iterator != 0) {
          temporaryDirectoryPath.push_back(*iterator);
          ++iterator;
        }
      }
```

`std::vector<char>` does not perform implicit null termination, unlike `std::string`. This works by accident if there happens to be a  null byte after the `"XXXXXX"` suffix. Whether that this is the case depends on the execution environment.

Comment: Oh dear, good catch! So I was playing the memory lottery and lucked out on the standalone and ideone checks. Thank you very much.